# Converting selector expression to predicate expression

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, lambda, expression

I need a way to convert a *selector expression* into a *predicate expression* in order to pass it to a query provider along with some parameters.

```
private Expression<Func<T, TKey>> PrimaryKeySelector { get; set; }

private ISpecification<T> GetByPrimaryKeySpecification(TKey key) {
   lambda = ... // some magic, also unicorns
   return new ExpressionSpecification(lambda);
}
```

In a first try I built the *predicate expression* using `Expression.Equal`, however this caused problems with query providers that analyze the expression (e.g. NHibernate failed because of unknown `Equal` statement). Also, I've seen solutions that create new `ParameterExpression`s and use the result of the *selector expression* by invoking it, however I feel this is just bad because 1) performance and 2) the parameter expression is already included in the *selector expression*.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking to do here is to compose one expression with another.  Doing this with functions is very easy; doing it with expressions takes a bit more work.

What you can do is replace all instances of the parameter to your second expression, the predicate, with the body of your first function, the selector.

```
public static Expression<Func<TFirstParam, TResult>>
    Compose<TFirstParam, TIntermediate, TResult>(
    this Expression<Func<TFirstParam, TIntermediate>> first,
    Expression<Func<TIntermediate, TResult>> second)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TFirstParam), "param");

    var newFirst = first.Body.Replace(first.Parameters[0], param);
    var newSecond = second.Body.Replace(second.Parameters[0], newFirst);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TFirstParam, TResult>>(newSecond, param);
}
```

This relies on the following method to replace all instances of one expression with another:

```
public static Expression Replace(this Expression expression,
    Expression searchEx, Expression replaceEx)
{
    return new ReplaceVisitor(searchEx, replaceEx).Visit(expression);
}
internal class ReplaceVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly Expression from, to;
    public ReplaceVisitor(Expression from, Expression to)
    {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }
    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        return node == from ? to : base.Visit(node);
    }
}
```

The final missing puzzle piece is that you won't be able to use the `==` operator to compare your values in a generic method as you won't be able to be sure that the type overlads the `==` operator; you'll need to build that equality expression manually:

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> EqualsValue<T>(T value)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var body = Expression.Equal(param, Expression.Constant(value));
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, param);
}
```

This allows you to write:

```
return PrimaryKeySelector.Compose(EqualsValue(key));
```

As to your concerns about performance, don't worry about it.  The amount of time that you'll be spending building up an expression tree like this is going to be *many orders of magnitude* slower than the network requests that you'll be making with them.  Spending a little extra time on the expression manipulation isn't even going to have a measurable effect on the performance of your application; it will be well below the *noise* of the network request.

Comment: Mh. This somehow doesn't work because of the error 'Cannot apply operator == to operands of type 'TKey' and 'TKey'. See my current implementation here: http://pastebin.com/iEt5ynNb

Comment: @xvdiff If you're not in a context where you can know the type of the key then you'll need to build that expression manually, rather than using a lambda, see edit.

Comment: But then NHibernate makes boom. -> System.NotSupportedException: Boolean Equals(System.Object)

Comment: @xvdiff The Expression.Equal method represents an `==` operator, not a call to the `Equals` method.  You must be calling `Equals` somewhere else in your expression.

Comment: Interesting. I can't find a call to Equals. I've got the KeySelector, the Spec and all I do is requesting .Query<> from NHibernate which then the Spec get's applied to.